# How to receive large file over networkstream c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, transfer

Im connecting 2 devices over TCPClient and TCPListener and im sending just a string for now and its all working:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");
clientStream.Write(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
clientStream.Flush();
```

and then

```
bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
Console.WriteLine("Mensageee"+ encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

But now i need to send a large file over it like 10mb or maybe more so should i use this?

```
 string doc = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(doc + filedir)
        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[file.Length];
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        networkStream.Write(file.ToArray(), 0, fileBuffer.GetLength(0));
        networkStream.Close();
```

And how should i receive all this file and then save it somewhere?
Any help is welcome thanks o/

Comment: Why are you calling `ToArray()` on a `byte[]`? It's not clear what your `fileBuffer` variable is for either... what's wrong with `networkStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length)`?

Comment: You're right, i guess i can just use networkStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length), that was just a random example i found. The problems is how do i receive this large file with the listener and how do i get feedback about how much is still missing so i can update a progress bar?

Comment: Well you can't know how much data there's going to be in the future unless you put that in the stream somewhere... you need to think about your protocol. Do you need to be able to send multiple messages in the same connection, for example?

Comment: All i need to do is send a .zip file one time and then close the connection. 1 file 1 time just that, the problem ( im not sure if its a problem ) is that this zip file may have from 100kb to 100mb just that.

Comment: If you don't need to show progress updates, you can probably get away with `Stream.CopyTo(otherStream)`.

Comment: And if you need to show progress updates, consider using `BinaryWriter` or `BitConverter` to send the length in 4 bytes (if you're happy with a 2GB limit; 8 bytes otherwise) first. Then on the receiving side, loop round reading into a buffer and writing it out somewhere, raising progress notifications as you go.

Comment: It's the first time im doing this i dont know how fast does this transfer goes but i do need to show a progress bar for my user to know how much is missing to send and receive.

Comment: Any samples or tutorials for me to follow? As i said im not familiar with this Bynary stuff.

Comment: I'm guessing that the xamarin tag indicates that this is for an Android app?

Comment: Yes it is my Steven Friend, actually is for iOS but im doing it first in android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is, you send a `byte[]` multiple times...

Essentially, you will need to fill a buffer ('byte[]') with a subset of the file:

```
int count = fileIO.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

And then send the buffer over the socket:

```
clientSocket.Send(buffer, 0, count);
```

Just do these two processes until you have sent the entire file... (Which will be when `count <= 0`)  However, the server has to know how many bytes to read... so we should start out by sending a `Int64` with the file's length.

**What we have so far...**

```
using (var fileIO = File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\fake.bin"))
using(var clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(ip, port).GetStream())
{
  // Send Length (Int64)
  clientSocket.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(fileIO.Length, 0, 8));

  var buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
  int count;
  while ((count = fileIO.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    clientSocket.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

**Server Side**

```
Int64 bytesReceived = 0;
int count;
var buffer = new byte[1024*8];

// Read length - Int64
clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, 8);
Int64 numberOfBytes = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);

using(var fileIO = File.Create("@c:\some\path"))
  while(bytesReceived < numberOfBytes && (count = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    fileIO.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    bytesReceived += count;
  }
```

Comment: Understood the logic, im just getting "Operation not supported" in this line "clientStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(clientStream.Length), 0 , 8);"

Comment: And how will this "clientStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(clientStream.Length), 0 , 8);"
To know how large is my file i didn't get that, where is this line, that will say the size of my file, connected with tmy FileIO?

Comment: My mistake, it should be `fileIO.Length`

Comment: Oh my bad 2, i couldn't fix on my own.. Well testing it now

Comment: Yea, the problem was `clientStream.Length`, it should be `fileIO.Length`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Well it worked fine thanks but as im passing a zip file its saying "unexpected end of file" when i try do extract it, i guess i need to somehow "close" my file dont i?

Comment: Where are you unzipping it...  If you do it outside the `using` block's scope, the file will be closed.

Comment: I am extracting it after closing my app and after all process is done, but im getting that message ( extracting on windows explorer ).

Comment: Then it might be because you're somehow not sending the entire file.  Ensure that the sizes on both sides are the same.

Comment: Actually now that im looking closer theres a difference on 7267 kbs or maybe 1024*8 bytes? Maybe the last package is not going?

Comment: Well `1024 * 8` is `8192`.  But it could be because the last one isn't sending. I had also forgot to add `bytesReceived += count;` (That's what I get for writing code directly in SO)

Comment: I putted a Console.Writeline after that while and it never reaches it,  i guess it never reaches the tcpClient.Close(); too...

Comment: Did you add the `bytesReceived += count`? If not, your socket will just sit and wait for more data.

Comment: Yes i did but still nothing below the while is happening :/

Comment: Well actually it was entering all times it needed in the while but was never moving on so i just putted a break; when bytesReceived == numberOfBytes and it closed and worked... so i guess its fine

Comment: Well then try it with the conditional as `bytesReceived <= numberOfBytes` and tell me if that works. Do that without the `break` statement.

Comment: I already did change that sorry not warning here and it was still not passing trough the while, as i said it is like sending all the packs but was just getting stuck in the while i dont know why